# Parsing JSON file and extracting keys and values using Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark. I have tried to parse the below mentioned JSON file in spark using SparkSQL but it didn't work. Can someone please help me to resolve this.

### InputJSON:

`[{"num":"1234","Projections":[{"Transactions":[{"14:45":0,"15:00":0}]}]}]`

### Expected output:

```
1234 14:45 0\n
1234 15:00 0
```

I have tried with the below code but it did not work

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs:/user/aswin/test.json").toDF();
val sql_output = sqlContext.sql("SELECT num, Projections.Transactions FROM df group by Projections.TotalTransactions ")
sql_output.collect.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
[01532,WrappedArray(WrappedArray([0,0]))]
```

Comment: Can you share what have you already tried? We can help you finding bug in your code.

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: Why are you collecting? Try `sql_output.show()` for the Dataframe

Comment: Also, you select 2 columns, but expect 3 columns?

Comment: I have tried with show and got the below response.

+-----+--------------------+
|  NUM|   Transactions|
+-----+--------------------+
|01532|[WrappedArray([0,...|
+-----+--------------------+

I have no idea how to select the keys like 14:45 in sql query

Answer (score 2):

Spark recognizes your `{"14:45":0,"15:00":0}` map as structure so probably the only way to read your data is to specify schema manually:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> schema = StructType([StructField('num', StringType()), StructField('Projections', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('Transactions', ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())))])))])
```

Then you can query this temporary table to get results using multiple exploding:

```
>>> sqlContext.read.json('sample.json', schema=schema).registerTempTable('df')
>>> sqlContext.sql("select num, explode(col) from (select explode(col.Transactions), num from (select explode(Projections), num from df))").show()
+----+-----+-----+
| num|  key|value|
+----+-----+-----+
|1234|14:45|    0|
|1234|15:00|    0|
+----+-----+-----+
```